# Vector of String not working when assiging strings using equals operator in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am trying this Code

```
string str;
    ll size=0;
    vector<string> finalStr;
    while(getline(cin, str)) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) 
        {
            if(count)
            {
                if(str[i]=='"') 
                {
                    str.erase(i, 1);
                    str.insert(i,"``"); 
                    count = false;
                }
            }
            if(!count) 
            {
                if(str[i]=='"') 
                {
                    str.erase(i, 1);
                    str.insert(i,"''"); 
                    count = true;
                }   
            }
        }
        finalStr[size++] = str;
    }
```

This Code doesn't work. I need reason why it is working when I am using `finStr.push_back(str)`.
Above Code is working good Till I Assigned the input string to my vector of String using equals operator.

Comment: `finalStr[size++] = str;` invokes *undefined behavior*, accessing an element that doesn't exist. There is no `finalStr[size]` element; the vector is empty from inception and nothing your code does changes that.

Comment: `finStr.push_back(str)` is how to add an item to the vector.  `finalStr[i]` is how to access or replace an item in the vector.

Comment: Thanks for Help. Now I have clear Idea.